# auto login to admin panel from an external file( out side magento root directory)

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-login

```
require_once 'mystore/app/Mage.php';
 umask(0);
 Mage::app('default'); 
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->loadByUsername('admin');
if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->renewSecretUrls();
}

$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setIsFirstVisit(true);
$session->setUser($user);
$session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success',array('user'=>$user));

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
  echo "Logged in";
  $redirectUrl = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getUrl(Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getStartupPageUrl(), array('_current' => false));
  header('Location: ' . $redirectUrl);
    exit;
}
```

It is **redirecting to the admin panel** **but shows the login page**. Is it possible show the dashboard as the admin is already logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I will not get into how much of a security hole this code would expose. I am sure that you know what you are doing.

First of all, you are loading up the "default" store. You should be loading the "admin" store `Mage::app(0)` or `Mage::app('admin')`.

I don't understand what you are doing with line 4 of your code... you should probably just use:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');

// don't mess with the existing admin session
if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    $session->refreshAcl();

    // redirect has to go somewhere... 
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/dashboard/'));
} else {
    // continue on with login code here
}
```

The Magento Admin login code is handled in:

```
Mage_Admin_Model_Observer::actionPreDispatchAdmin()
```

Comment: I installed manthan extension for multi vendor store.I am trying to login to the vendor panel from the frontend.Your suggestion returns the same result as it is not redirecting to the dashboard and stays in the login page.Do you have any  suggestion?

Comment: The example code was not complete, and I am not familiar with the manthan extension.